# Datagrid won't clear

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

The datagrid I have made won't let me clear the values. When I attempt to do a `datagrid.columns.clear();` then it scrunches the rows together and doesn't display anything more than lines and it still doesn't clear.

I have tried  `datagrid.items.clear();` as I have used `Datagrid.items.add();` to add items to my datagrid. I have tried `datagrid.items.refresh();` and setting the datacontext to null. None of this is working.

```
public  void FillDataGridWithCustInfo()
        {



            CustomerDataGrid.Items.Clear();

            CustomerDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;

            CustomerDataGrid.Items.Refresh();


            int ArrayNum = 0;

            Int32 length = CustomerFirstName.Count;

            while (length > ArrayNum)
            {




                CustomerInformation TempCust = new CustomerInformation();
                TempCust.FirstName = CustomerFirstName[ArrayNum];
                TempCust.MiddleInital = CustomerMiddleInitial[ArrayNum];
                TempCust.LastName = CustomerLastName[ArrayNum];
                TempCust.TaxClass = CustomerTaxClass[ArrayNum];
                TempCust.Email = CustomerEmail[ArrayNum];

                CustomerDataGrid.Items.Add(TempCust);




                ArrayNum = ArrayNum + 1;

            }





        }
```

I want it to clear the datagrid before filling it when I close out of this particular window, but it is currently taking all the data in the datagrid and just adding to it so I am getting duplicates of all the information.

Comment: Can you instead create a `List<CustomerInformation>` and set the `ItemsSource` instead? That is the expected way of doing it.

Comment: I have it connected through a List<CustomerFirstName> and cleared the list out. That seems to be working.

Comment: It will be better to use an ObservableCollection<T> for avoiding further problems.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure is datagrid was use by desktop application , in web application we have a similar object call as gridview which show data as table format. If you want to force clear all row , you can assign an empty or dummy data table , something like below shall do the trick..

```
     GridView1.DataSource = new DataTable();
     GridView1.DataBind();
```

If you want to maintain proper column header and just want to remove row that contain data  , make sure you proper structure your datatable..something like this.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Column1", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Column2", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: My WPF won't let me use 'Datagrid.DataSource' It tells me that I am missing a reference.